# PHP Spreadsheet - Reading a locked sheet fails

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PhpSpreadsheet to read excel sheets and parse their contents. I haven't had a problem with most of the files that I'm uploading.

However, a recent change in policy meant that the sheets will be locked. The file can be opened normally without needing a password, and the data can still be entered and saved using Excel without using a password.

However, the PHP script I'm using can't parse the files anymore. Here's the code I'm using:

```
use vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\reader\Exception;


function upload_details($path){

    echo "upload_details hit!<br>\n";
    echo "path = $path<br>\n";


    $reader;

    if(strpos($path, "xlsx")){
        $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx');
    }
    else{
        $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xls');
    }

    echo "got our file<br>\n";

    $reader->setReadDataOnly(FALSE);
    echo "got our reader<br>\n";

    try{
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($path);        
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        die('error laoding file: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    echo "got our spreadsheet<br>\n";

    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    echo "got our worksheet!! <br>\n";


...
}
```

When using the old files where the sheets are unlocked, the code executes without any problems at all.

However, when I use the new file with the locked sheets, I only get to up the `$reader->setReadDataOnly(FALSE);` part. The code stops at the `$spreadsheet = $reader->load($path);` part. I've added a try-catch block to try and get the error, but to no avail.

I checked the documentation, but to no avail. There doesn't seem to be any leads as to how I can access the data in a locked sheet. The sheets have to remain locked during the upload and parsing method, I can't unlock the sheets and save them again.

Comment: If I remember correctly, use : `$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getProtection()->setLocked(false);` to unlock the sheet first

Comment: @KenLee I tried placing `$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getProtection()->setLocked(false);` before and after my `$spreadsheet = $reader->load($path);` but I got the same error.

Comment: unlock it, **save** it, close it and then reopen it please (perform all steps by PHP)

Comment: I don't think I have the option to unlock it due to some business process specification.

Comment: do all steps by PHP (unlock / save /close / re-open)

Comment: No I mean, I can't unlock it even if I have the password, save, close, and reopen. The sheets need to stay locked.

Comment: Then do this : unlock / save /close / re-open / reading data / **lock it back**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248548/discussion-between-razgriz-and-ken-lee).